# Thymeleaf & Spring: avoid duplicating REST requests for storage into Thymeleaf model class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to display the same list in a `<select>` field every time a user clicks some URL links that are mapped to separate methods inside one controller.

The main problem is that the data in this list is fetched from another microservice and I have to request this data in every method inside the controller and this seems like an unnecessary code duplication.

Maybe there is a way to somehow store the value of this list globally?

Here is the current code from one of the controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/firms")
public String firm (Map <String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
        HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
    List <Country> countryList = firmService.getEuCountries(cookie, requestEntity);
    model.put("firm", new Firm());
    model.put("countryList", countryList); // <- this code is duplicated in each controller method
    return "firm";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the list in the session and only get it from the microservice if it isn't already present in the session, like so:

```
List <Country> countryList = httpSession.getAttribute("countryList");
if (countryList == null || countryList.isEmpty() {
    countryList = firmService.getEuCountries(cookie, requestEntity);
    httpSession.setAttribute("countryList", countryList);
}
model.put("countryList", countryList);
```

The code would still be "duplicated" but you could extract it to a method and use the method every time. This would save you a lot of requests and time.

Comment: Thanks! Is it considered ok to store such an object as a session parameter?

Comment: No Problem! I can't say anything about that, sadly. My team has used it with success but I can't say if it's ok from a design point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method that does the job and annotate it with `@ModelAttribute`.

But this method will be called for every method mapped by your controller and the `countryList` will be added to the model everytime.

You can then use some cache to avoid to call the API.
`

Comment: Duh! Totally forgot about this one! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I don't think this totally suits my needs if I understand correctly. This `countryList` object needs servletRequest, servletResponse & Cookie objects. It's basicly an object retrieved from another microservice. In this case I cannot use the @ModelAttribute, because I don't think this method allows all of above mentioned incoming parameters...

Comment: Why do you need these objects to get the `countryList` from the microservice ? You should not pass request, response and cookie objects as parameters to other methods.

Comment: because service form which this list is coming is secured. And I need to send a JWT token value from the cookie in the header of the request to get that list of countries...

Comment: Well maybe it's a bad practice, i don't know, but i would generate a static JWT Token for the server to call this API. I would not use the JWT Token from the client cookie because it's not the client who needs to call the API but the server that need it to deliver the page to the client.

Comment: maybe you're advising to store the token value in the session instead of cookies?

Comment: No i would get a JWT from this API with a long lifetime only once (at server's startup by example) and keep it in memory to use it everytime i need to call the API.